# Swap Image in ViewPager with Buttons

Tags: android, android-viewpager

When user press this LEFT or RIGHT button the image should swap according to left or right in ViewPager, The button is out side of the ViewPager.. Can any body help me how to do this

Comment: I have put One ViewPager and below of that ViewPager i have put two buttons named LEFT & RIGHT when user press Left or Right button the image should swipe in Viewpager

Comment: check if this suits you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGwG8-chUEM

Comment: Thanks a lot dilix, thanks a lot ya this is i was looking for but is it possible with viewpager????

Comment: in ViewPager you can setCurrentItem or scrollTo/scrollBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well is easy, you need to add code on the "onclick" of each button to do this:

```
ViewPager mPager = new ViewPager(mContext);  //replace mContext with "this" if in activity
int newPosition = mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;  //- 1 if is the left button
newPosition = newPosition < (mPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) ? newPosition : newPosition - 1;
//And again this is for right, for left you need to compare 'newPosition >= 0'
mPager.setCurrentItem(newPosition);
```